# how to fix internal server error 500 on ajax post in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my html code

```
@model IEnumerable<Sampletestapp.Data.UserInfo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    WebGrid webGrid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canSort: false, canPage: false);
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

@webGrid.GetHtml(
       htmlAttributes: new { @id = "WebGrid", @class = "Grid" },
       columns: webGrid.Columns(
                webGrid.Column("Id", "Id"),
                webGrid.Column("Name", "Name"),
                webGrid.Column("Lastname", "Lastname"),
                webGrid.Column("City", "City"),
                webGrid.Column("Country", "Country"),
                webGrid.Column("State", "State")))

<br />
<div class="Pager"></div>

<script src="~/Scripts/ASPSnippets_Pager.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        GetUsers(1);
    });


    function GetUsers(pageIndex) {    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
                data:'{pageIndex: ' + pageIndex + '}',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: OnSuccess,
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);

                }
            });
        };
        //your code here

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        alert('hi');
        var model = response;
        console.log(response);
        var row = $("#WebGrid tbody tr:last-child").clone(true);
        $("#WebGrid tbody tr").remove();
        $.each(model.users, function () {

            var user = this;
            $("td", row).eq(0).html(user.Id);
            $("td", row).eq(1).html(user.Name);
            $("td", row).eq(2).html(user.City);
            $("td", row).eq(3).html(user.Country);
            $("td", row).eq(4).html(user.State);
            $("#WebGrid").append(row);
            row = $("#WebGrid tbody tr:last-child").clone(true);
        });
        $(".Pager").ASPSnippets_Pager({
            ActiveCssClass: "current",
            PagerCssClass: "pager",
            PageIndex: 1,
            PageSize: 5,
            RecordCount: model.RecordCount
        });

    }

    $("body").on("click", function () {
        GetUsers(1);
    });


</script>
```

and controller code is

```
 public ActionResult Test()
        {
            ViewBag.Country = from result in db.tblcountries select result;
            ViewBag.City = from result in db.tblcities select result;

            List<UserInfo> dummy = new List<UserInfo>();
            dummy.Add(new UserInfo());
            return View(dummy);
            //return View();
        }
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AjaxMethod(int pageIndex)
{

    Users usermodel = new Users();
    usermodel.PageIndex = pageIndex;
    usermodel.PageSize = 10;
    usermodel.RecordCount = db.UserInfoes.Count();
    int startIndex = (pageIndex - 1) * usermodel.PageSize;

    usermodel.users = (from items in db.UserInfoes
                       select items)
                    .OrderBy(items => items.Id).Skip(startIndex)
                    .Take(usermodel.PageSize).ToList();

    return Json(usermodel);
}
```

bt i m getting internal server error and it is getting inside error function so please suggest where i m getting wrong

Comment: should be "OnSuccess(response)", no?  I recommend displaying the full error while debugging.  You can get the headers from jQuery, by adding .fail(function (jqXHR, status, error) { display_error_function (jqXHR, status, error); }); : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Comment: 500 means internal server error, put a break point in `AjaxMethod`

Comment: yes i did and it is resolved thanks alot